# Delete row with Match value from other worksheet Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I want to write some code that when I choose a cell then press Delete on sheet1 it will delete the entire selected row from sheet1 (ex: row 8) and do the same thing for the exact value on the Data sheet ( I want to use the PT-2 to find the exact row on the data sheet ) but I don't know how
[image: Sheet1][image: Data sheet][image: my VBA]

Answer (score 1):

This allows you to delete the row from both "Sheet1" and "Sheet2" each time you run the macro.

```html
Sub DeleteSelectedRow()
    Dim numRows As Long
    Dim i As Long

    numRows = ActiveCell.Row
    Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(numRows).Delete
    Sheets("Sheet2").Rows(numRows).Delete
End Sub
```